# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] after declaring controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started writing some code for a angular js course I am in and I'm getting this error in my console log (Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]) and I'm not sure why? I checked it out on angular's website and it says you are trying to call a controller that doesn't exist, or something along those lines. I checked and I had declared the controller, so I don't know why this error is coming up. Here is my code, Please help and thank you!

**js**:

```
(function () {
      'use strict';

      angular.module('narrowDownMenuApp', [])
      .controller('narrowItDownController ', narrowItDownController )
      .service('MenuSearchService', MenuSearchService);

      narrowItDownController.$inject = ['MenuSearchService'];
      function narrowItDownController(MenuSearchService) {
        var menu = this;
        menu.input = "";
        menu.search = function() {
          console.log("blah");
          MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm);
        }
      }
      MenuSearchService.$inject = ['$https'];
      function MenuSearchService($https) {
        var service = this;
        service.getMatchedMenuItems = function(searchTerm) {
          return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: ('https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/menu_items.json')
          }).then(function (result) {
              console.log(result);
            var foundItems

            // return processed items
            return foundItems;
          });
        }
      }
    })();
```

**html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="narrowDownMenuApp">

<head>
    <title>Narrow Down Your Menu Choice</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller='narrowItDownController as menu'>
        <h1>Narrow Down Your Chinese Menu Choice</h1>

        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search term" ng-model="menu.input"> {{menu.input}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <button ng-click="menu.search()">Narrow It Down For Me!</button>
        </div>

        <!-- found-items should be implemented as a component -->
        <found-items found-items="...." on-remove="...."></found-items>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.controller('narrowItDownController ', narrowItDownController )` remove the space. Did you see it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space is your controller initialization

```
.controller('narrowItDownController', narrowItDownController )
```

You also have to inject `$http` in your service

```
 MenuSearchService.$inject = ['$http'];
 function MenuSearchService($http) {
     ....
 }
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please state the reason so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but even after injecting the $http into my service I still get the Error: [$injector:unpr] error? Do you know why? Please help if you can. PS: I wasn't the one who downvoted

Comment: Did you remove the space in .controller('narrowItDownController'?

Comment: @Vivz I'm the one who downvoted. I accept that was a mistake. i just confused with `$http` and `$https` and i removed it.

Comment: @SankarRaj No problem. It is fine now that you have given the reason for downvote

Comment: @LucaCiancanelli Are you getting the error on click of search items? And found-items have been implemented as a component? If not and if you add it in template, it may throw an exception

Comment: Those were things that I was going to implement later in my code. But I am still getting the  Error: [$injector:unpr]  error.

Comment: Never mind I was able to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

there is space in your controller name in definition. remove that and your controller will work

```
 angular.module('narrowDownMenuApp', [])
      .controller('narrowItDownController', narrowItDownController )
```